# How can I bind a TextBlock to an ObjectDataProvider resource defined in app.xaml?

Tags: wpf, binding, mvvm, app.xaml

I have a WPF application with MVVM, it has an Ap.XAML that looks like this.

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/StyleDictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="SAG_POK" ObjectType="{x:Type or:SAG_POK}" />
    </ResourceDictionary>        
</Application.Resources>
```

Now, on the MainWindow.XAML I want to bind to the SAG_POK ObjectDataprovider in Ap.xaml.

```
<StackPanel
   DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource SAG_POK}}">
   <TextBlock Name="ValgtSag" Text="{Binding ToStringProperty}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

My problem is that in one of my viewmodels, I instantiate the SAG_POK ObjectDataProvider in App.xaml with an instance of SAG_POK.

```
App.Current.Resources["SAG_POK"] = SagSelecteditem;
```

But I can't figure out where to put my OnNotifyPropertyChanged("SAG_POK") I have tried different scenarios but none of them seems to work.

Anyone who has tried this before ?, please let me know of any hints, thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get it: Why do you use an ObjetcDataProvider when you already have ViewModels? Why not bind the View to the ViewModel directly?

Comment: Because the Objectdataprovider is used several places in the Application, and because the viewmodel is used on page, not by the window.

Comment: You don't "set" a resource like that.  It is instantiated when referenced and that instance is reused every time.  The way you're trying to use the ODP is bizarre.  Why not just add your SAG_POK instance as a resource?  Replace the ODP with the following:  `<or:SAG_POK x:Key="SAG_POK" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/StyleDictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <!--<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="SAG_POK" ObjectType="{x:Type or:SAG_POK}" />-->
        <local:MainViewModel x:Key="SAG_POK" />
    </ResourceDictionary>        
</Application.Resources>


<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource SAG_POK}}">
   <TextBlock Name="ValgtSag" Text="{Binding ToStringProperty}"/>
</StackPanel>

App.Current.Resources["SAG_POK"].SelectedItem = SagSelectedItem;
```

MainViewModel is yout main view model :-) in the hole application

hope this helps